# How to get a note node having particular hashtag value

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

This is my XML structure:

```
<Note Id="2" Category="OFFICE" Date="12/6/2014 12:00:00 AM">
    <Hashtag>#hashnotes</Hashtag>
    <Hashtag>#hashnotes</Hashtag>
    <Hashtag>#good</Hashtag>
    <Text>this is #hashnotes app #hashnotes are #good</Text>
</Note>
```

The code I am writing for searching the hashtag values using LINQ in C# is as follows:

```
var user = XmlDoc.Element("HashNotes").Elements("Note")
             .Where(e => e.Element("Hashtag").Value == hashtag);
```

But not able to search in deeper nodes.
Can you tell me how to extract the value of Elements having the same name Hashtag?

Comment: You question is not clear. You want all the elements which have same value in `Hashtag` node? or only those `Hashtag` node having a specific value?

Comment: I want to extract all elements having value=#hashnotes

Comment: @zombie, do you mean you want to get duplicates?

Comment: if i am checking for #hashnotes i should get 2 nodes since here i have two nodes having same hashtag value.But in my code its only checking the first element.Its not going deeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code would return the `Note` element which contains and `#hashtag` values.

Refine the search further by adding another layer, eg,

```
var list = doc.Element("HashNotes")
              .Elements("Note")
              .Elements("Hashtag")
              .Where(p=>p.Value == "#hashnotes");
```

This will now return the `Hashtag` elements.

// Update

To extract the relevant Note element, you can simply invoke the `.Parent` property for the expected index.

```
int idx_wanted = 0;
return list[idx_wanted].Parent;
```

Comment: but its only checking the first element node.Since i have multiple elements with name <hashtag> i want a code that will check all the elements

Comment: @zombie, above code returns all hashtags. Have you tried?

Comment: Thanx....that is working...what will be the generic code like if i have to extract the value from the text box.Like somebody wants to search for particular #hashtag.

Comment: @zombie I am not sure what you mean by generic.  I knocked the sample together quickly, but you can replace `"#hashnotes"` with a variable; Which can then be populated from a textbox or any other source - is this what you mean?

Comment: What if i have to return a note element in list

Comment: @zombie The list variable would be a list of `XElement` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.100).aspx) objects.  So, you could get the relevant Note element by using `.Parent` property.  I have updated the code sample.

Comment: @Kami like if i want all the relevent information like id,category,date,text of the node having hashtag=#hashnotes so how can i write linq querry for that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how to do it:

```
stirng Xml = @"<Note Id='2' Category='OFFICE' Date='12/6/2014 12:00:00 AM'>
                    <Hashtag>#hashnotes</Hashtag>
                    <Hashtag>#hashnotes</Hashtag>
                    <Hashtag>#good</Hashtag>
                    <Text>this is #hashnotes app #hashnotes are #good</Text>
                    </Note>";

string SearchParam = "#hashnotes";
XElement element = XElement.Parse(Xml);

var nodes= element.Descendants("Hashtag").Where(e => e.Value == SearchParam);
```

If you want to do from a xml file on disk then:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("FileUri");

var nodes = document.Descendants("Hashtag").Where(e => e.Value == SearchParam);
```

I am loading xml as string, in your case it can also be as string or from xml file.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:-

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"YourXMLPath.xml");
List<string> result = xdoc.Descendants("Note").Elements("Hashtag")
                         .Where(x => x.Value == hashtag) 
                         .Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

But, this will obviously give the list of same value `hashtag`, if you need the complete node, don't apply the `Value` property.

**Update:**

To retrieve other values, you can do this:--

```
var result = xdoc.Descendants("Hashtag")
                         .Where(x => x.Value == hashtag)
                         .Select(x => new 
                            {
                                HashTag = x.Value,
                                Id = x.Parent.Attribute("Id").Value,
                                Category = x.Parent.Attribute("Category").Value,
                                Date = x.Parent.Attribute("Date").Value
                            });
```

Comment: i want all the relevent information like id,category,date,text of the node having hashtag=#hashnotes so how can i write linq querry for that

Comment: But after this if i am writing foreach loop then the error message is dispalyed.I am quoting the error message"Cannot convert type 'String' to 'System.Xml.linq.XElement'

Comment: @zombie - Thats because we are fetching an `anonymous` type and not string. Your loop should be like: `foreach(var item in result) { }`

Comment: No i have to maintain a nodelist from the search results.Thanx anyways